# Optimizing removing duplicates in large files in Python

Tags: python, optimization, duplicates, large-files

I have one very large text file(27GB) that I am attempting to make smaller by removing lines that are duplicated in a second database that has several files of a more reasonable size(500MB-2GB).  I have some functional code, what I am wondering is is there any way I can optimize this code to run faster, human clock time?  At the moment, on a small test run with a 1.5GB input and 500MB filter, this takes 75~ seconds to complete.

I've gone through many iterations of this idea, this one is currently best for time, if anyone has ideas for making a better logical structure for the filter I'd love to hear it, past attempts that have all been worse than this one: Loading the filter into a set and cycling through the input searching for duplicates(about half as fast as this), loading the input into a set and running the filter through a difference_update(almost as fast as this but also doing the reverse of what I wanted), and loading both input and filter into sets in chunks and doing set differences(that was a horrible, horrible idea that would work(maybe?) if my filters were smaller so I didn't have to split them, too.)

So, those are all the things I've tried.  All of these processes max out on CPU, and my final version runs at about 25-50% disk I/O, filter and output are on one physical disk, input is on another.  I am running a dual core and have no idea if this particular script can be threaded, never done any multithreading before so if that's a possibility I'd love to be pointed in the right direction.

Information about the data!  As said earlier, the input is many times larger than the filter.  I am expecting a very small percentage of duplication.  The data is in lines, all of which are under 20 ASCII characters long.  The files are all sorted.

I've already changed the order of the three logical statements, based on the expectation that unique input lines will be the majority of the lines, then unique filter, then duplicates, which on the 'best' case of having no duplicates at all, saved me about 10% time.

Any suggestions?

```
def sortedfilter(input,filter,output):
    file_input = open(input,'r')
    file_filter = open(filter,'r')
    file_output = open(output,'w')
    inline = file_input.next()
    filterline = file_filter.next()
    try:
        while inline and filterline:
            if inline < filterline:
                file_output.write(inline)
                inline = file_input.next()
                continue
            if inline > filterline:
                filterline = file_filter.next()
                continue
            if inline == filterline:
                filterline = file_filter.next()
                inline = file_input.next()
    except StopIteration:
        file_output.writelines(file_input.readlines())
    finally:
        file_filter.close()
        file_input.close()
        file_output.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be interested in knowing how this compares; it's basically just playing with the order of iteration a bit.

```
def sortedfilter(in_fname, filter_fname, out_fname):
    with open(in_fname) as inf, open(filter_fname) as fil, open(out_fname, 'w') as outf:
        ins = inf.next()
        try:
            for fs in fil:
                while ins < fs:
                    outf.write(ins)
                    ins = inf.next()
                while ins == fs:
                    ins = inf.next()
        except StopIteration:
            # reached end of inf before end of fil
            pass
        else:
            # reached end of fil first, pass rest of inf through
            file_output.writelines(file_input.readlines())
```

Comment: This is better than mine by 15% or so on the worst case of all duplicates, and the same for no duplicates, so I'll be changing up my logic a little!  I also made a tiny tweak to my code, `while inline and filterline` changed to `while True` since it always breaks on StopIteration anyways, which got me a few percent.   Is there anything inherently 'better' about loading files in the way you and cravoori have done, or is it simply to condense the script a little?

Comment: @Briana : That way of loading files is more pythonic. You do not have to close the files that way.

Comment: @Hugh I just went through this again and found one more place to improve, because the data I am looking at is guaranteed to be sorted and unique in each file, this line `while ins == fs:` can actually be an if, even further reducing the time when there are duplicates found, down to around 60% of my original time for an all-duplicate test case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the string comparison operation only once per line by executing `cmp(inline, filterline)`:

- `-1` means `inline < filterline`
- `0` means `inline == filterline`
- `+1` means `inline < filterline`.

This might get you a few extra percent. So something like:

```
    while inline and filterline:
        comparison = cmp(inline, filterline)
        if comparison == -1:
            file_output.write(inline)
            inline = file_input.next()
            continue
        if comparison == 1:
            filterline = file_filter.next()
            continue
        if comparison == 0:
            filterline = file_filter.next()
            inline = file_input.next()
```

Comment: I like this, and I tested it, and it turns out that writing it to memory and reading it 1-3 times is actually slower than doing the calculation repeatedly.  This very well could be faster on a system with better RAM though.

Comment: @Briana Really? I'm surprised. Have you had a go at this code with cProfile to see where it's spending the time?

Comment: I've never worked with cProfile before, so I'm not sure if I can pull up more data with it than this, but these are the two results, with and without the cmp.   [link](http://pastebin.com/RfPA3RwD)

Answer (score 1):

seeing that your input files are sorted, the following should work. heapq's merge produces a sorted stream from sorted inputs upon which groupby operates; groups whose lengths are greater than 1 are discarded. This stream-based approach should have relatively low memory requirements

```
from itertools import groupby, repeat, izip
from heapq import merge
from operator import itemgetter

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file_input, open('filter.txt', 'r') as file_filter, open('output.txt', 'w') as file_output:
  file_input_1 = izip(file_input, repeat(1))
  file_filter_1 = izip(file_filter, repeat(2))
  gen = merge(file_input_1, file_filter_1)
  gen = ((k, list(g)) for (k, g) in groupby(gen, key=itemgetter(0)))
  gen = (k for (k, g) in gen if len(g) == 1 and g[0][1]  == 1)
  for line in gen:
    file_output.write(line)
```

Comment: When I try to run this with my inputs I get an error, and I haven't played with heapq before so I'm not familiar with what its inputs/outputs look like to figure out why it's breaking.

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: 2.7, I actually just got this working, grabbed it again after your last edit, I'm not sure if you changed the code or not other than the inputs or if I was screwing something up before.  I think you misread what I was trying to do, I don't want to merge the files, which this does, removing duplicates while it's doing so, I wanted to remove duplicates from one file, while leaving the other one intact and separate.

Comment: I see. I have modified the code now to ensure that records from the filter file are not picked up in the merge process. This involves using itertools.repeat to associate a file-specific number with each record from input files and then filtering based on that number to ensure that only records from the input file are written to the output file; records from the filter file are not written to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider opening your files as binary so no conversion to unicode needs to be made:

```
with open(in_fname,'rb') as inf, open(filter_fname,'rb') as fil, open(out_fname, 'wb') as outf:
```

Comment: Very slight improvement, I'll take it!  As of python 2.5 it the b has to come after the r/w/a mode.